# Flutter dependencies break when project is moved

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter project I am working on. I decided to move it to another folder (which I use for my GitHub repositories) when the project went from playing around to becoming more serious.

However, this caused two dependencies to break:

shared_preferences: ^0.4.3

onesignal: ^1.0.5

Here is the error I am getting (basically, Flutter/Flutter.h can't be imported):

```
=== BUILD TARGET OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
In file included from /Users/rgb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.4.3/ios/Classes/SharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
/Users/rgb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.4.3/ios/Classes/SharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
=== BUILD TARGET OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
In file included from /Users/rgb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/onesignal-1.0.5/ios/Classes/OneSignalPlugin.m:28:
/Users/rgb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/onesignal-1.0.5/ios/Classes/OneSignalPlugin.h:28:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
```

I have tried removing and adding the dependencies, even deleting the dependency files from disk, Flutter Clean, Package Get but nothing seems to work.

Flutter Doctor has no complaints.

Any ideas?

Comment: It look's like the problem is with One Signal service.  Try to delete whole ios folder and run flutter build ios again